# How to identify different types of NA data

Tags: r, stata, na

I have a data set that has been imported into R from Stata, but was delivered to me as a .rda (I don't have access to the original Stata data set). Many of the fields are of class : `"haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"`.  The data is coded such that there are different types of `NA`.

Here you can see an example of the labels and the different types of `NA`s
[image: (NA(a), NA(b), and NA(c))]

Unfortunately, R seems to interpret them all as a `NA`. When viewing the data in R Studio using `View(dataframe)` or when creating plots, all `NA` types show up as "NA" and cannot be differentiated between. However, when viewing the data in the R console the different types do show up.

Viewing the data with `View()`:

[image: Viewing the data with View()]

Data in the R Console:
[image: Data in the R Console]

I need to be able to differentiate between the NA(c) values and the others (NA(a), NA(b)) for data analysis, but I cannot figure out how to get R to recognize that they are different.

Unfortunately, I can't make a reproducible example because I don't understand what is going on with these NAs. Is it possible to separate them out?

Any help or insight about how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: Thank you for the responses!

Here is the output of
`dput(head(lapop$psc1n))`:

[image: dput]

Here is an example of a simple bar graph:

```
`ggplot(lapop, aes(as.factor(psc1n))) +
       geom_bar()`
```

gives me:

[image]

Here I would need to exclude out the NA(c)s, which are the majority, and see the NA "a" and "b"s as separate categories.

I am currently looking at the `replace_na()` function from the sjmisc package that G. Grothendieck mentioned and I think it will help.

Comment: Look at the sjmisc, sjlabelled and memisc packages.

Comment: Can you (1) post your first and third images as text rather than images, (2) post the results of `dput(head(lapop$psc1n))`  (3) give us an example of something you would want to do with the data (other than `View()`, which is a special case) - for example, how would you like to view differentiated missing values in a plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this very easily using the `replace_na()` function from the sjmisc package suggested by Grothendieck. I found the `count_na()` function from sjlabelled package helpful for validation/checking the counts of each NA type as I went.

Thanks for the responses and formatting help.

```
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

## checking counts of each NA type
count_na(data$psc1n)

## replacing the meaningful NA values
data$temp <- replace_na(data$psc1n, value = 999,tagged.na = "a")
data$temp <- replace_na(data$temp, value = 888,tagged.na = "b")

## filtering out respondents who were not asked questions of interest (NA(c)s)
data_filtered <- data[is.na(data$temp)== FALSE,]

## checking that the data set only has the NAs of interest
count_na(data_filtered$psc1n)

## creating the graph with NA values b and c separated out
ggplot(data_filtered, aes(as.factor(temp))) +
    geom_bar()
```

[image: graph with NA(c)s filtered out + different categories for NA(a) and NA(b)]